# Enabling CORS in TomEE causes 404 on all routes

Tags: cors, apache-tomee, javax

I've enabled CORS in my TomEE web server using the following `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>Spotitube</display-name>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
            <param-value>10</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Since this change all my routes are returning 404, from the same origin as well as from another origin. Does anyone know what could be causing this?
I've also tried the most basic TomEE cors filter from here: https://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html but that just causes the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have declared the filter twice. Remove the redundand declaration (both  filter and filter-mapping). In your second declaration the url-pattern is just "\*", but it should be "/*"

Comment: I've notices this as well and have since then changed it, that doesn't fix the issue though ..

Comment: @SvetlinZarev do you have any clue?

Answer (score 0):

did you intend to set `metadata-complete="true"`? It deactivate some scanning so you might want to keep it to false

what do you deploy on the server? this web.xml doesn't have a servlet so I guess it should be something scanned or so?